# How to identify photos that were downloaded from Facebook

Tags: facebook, imagemagick, exif, photos

Is there any kind of metadata in photos that Facebook processes that could be used to figure out if a photo originated from Facebook?

For example, is there any data I could extract from a resized jpg file downloaded from Facebook using ImageMagick or some other tool?

I don't see any way to do this right now other than to guess by filename (which I don't have in this case) or by dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

AFAICS there is no way to discover any special metadata or EXIF data in photos that are downloaded from Facebook.

*'Originated from Facebook'* (your expression) in any way is wrongly stated. People upload lots of stuff to Facebook, but that doesn't mean it *originates* from there...

If you can provide any sample of fotos you are thinking of, one could start investigating a bit closer....

Comment: Right. By originated from Facebook I mean a photo that was downloaded from Facebook which presumably came from a camera. The first step would be to identify that a photo was downloaded from Facebook. Maybe I could make an educated guess using the EXIF if they always recompress a certain way but that's not worth the effort for a fuzzy match. Ultimately, my goal would be to detect that a photo was downsized and be able to prompt the user to find the original file if possible (imagine a photo printing website). I've reached a similar conclusion as you and don't see a reliable way to detect this.